# React Hook doesn't re-render array.map after state change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, render

Today I'm trying to render some reactHooks by iterating through arrays.

The issue I'm encountering now is the re-render that doesn't take place on a `tileMap` state update.

`tileMap` is an array of array of object (cf. end of post)

The state changes, I can log it with right values but still no render of the Tile components

```js
function resetGame() {
        console.log("yo");
        
        let tileMap = []
        
        //tileMap is updated here

        //This is always reached
        setTileMap(tileMap)
    }
```

```js
<div className="life2dgame-root">      
   {
      
      tileMap ? 
        tileMap.map((row) => {
           row.map((tile) => {
              console.log(tile);
                 return <Tile isLife={tile.isAlive}/>
              })
            })
        :
        null
   }
</div>
```

Type of the tileMap state

```js
<{
    loc: {height: number, width: number},
    element: JSX.Element,
    isAlive: boolean
}[][]>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Try to add full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning anything from `tileMap.map`.  Add a return and you should see something.

```
tileMap.map((row) => {
  return row.map((tile) => {
    return <Tile isLife={tile.isAlive}/>
  })
})
```

Comment: That didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

React uses key to decide which elements to rerender; because you don't have set keys in your map function, React won't update anything. Try:

```
tileMap ? 
        tileMap.map((row, index) => {
           row.map((tile) => {
              console.log(tile);
                 return <Tile key={`${row + index}} isLife={tile.isAlive}/>
              })
            })
        :
        null
```

Edit:

You can put whatever you want in the key, I don't know the value of your `row` variable so I joined it with the index, but you can put anything as long as it stays unique.